# Maven liquibase not replacing all properties

Tags: sql-server, maven, liquibase

I have a LiquiBase setup which works very well for Oracle SQL scripts. We are migrating DB logic to Microsoft SQL Server, and we found that in one SQL block, some POM properties are not replaced by Maven. Here is the pom.xml setting the properties:

```
<properties>
    <version.mssql-jdbc>7.4.1.jre8</version.mssql-jdbc>
    <version.org.liquibase.liquibase-maven-plugin>3.6.2</version.org.liquibase.liquibase-maven-plugin>
    <liquibase.url>jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x</liquibase.url>
    <!-- liquibase.url>offline:oracle?outputLiquibaseSql=true</liquibase.url -->
    <liquibase.execute.goal>update</liquibase.execute.goal>
    <liquibase.driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</liquibase.driver>
    <admin.db.name>sa</admin.db.name>
    <admin.db.password>xxx</admin.db.password>
    <custom.db.name>CUSTOM_USERNAME</custom.db.name>
    <custom.db.password>CUSTOM_PASSWORD</custom.db.password>

    <database.filelocation>D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.LAB\\MSSQL\\DATA\\</database.filelocation>
</properties>
```

Here is the base SQL with the properties included:

```
USE [master];
GO
-- Creating logins
CREATE LOGIN ${custom.db.name} WITH PASSWORD = '${custom.db.password}';
GO

-- Creating users for the logins
CREATE USER ${custom.db.name} FOR LOGIN ${custom.db.name};
GO

-- Granting permissions to the users
GRANT CONNECT TO ${custom.db.name};
GO

GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO ${custom.db.name};
GO

USE [msdb];
GO
-- Procedure for the housekeeping job

CREATE PROCEDURE hk_job_starter_${custom.db.name}
AS
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
        EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}',@step_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}_STEP',@subsystem = N'TSQL',@command = N'USE [${custom.db.name}]; EXEC PKG_HOUSEKEEPING.CLEANUP_DAILY;',@retry_attempts = 5,@retry_interval = 5;
        DECLARE @start_date VARCHAR(8);
        SELECT @start_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)));
        EXEC sp_add_schedule @schedule_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}_SCHEDULE', @freq_type = 4, @freq_interval = 1, @freq_subday_type = 0x8, @freq_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_date = @start_date, @active_start_time = 010000;
        EXEC sp_attach_schedule @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}', @schedule_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}_SCHEDULE';
        EXEC sp_add_jobserver   @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
        EXEC sp_start_job       @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';

    END;
GO

CREATE USER ${custom.db.name} FOR LOGIN ${custom.db.name};
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON hk_job_starter_${custom.db.name} TO ${custom.db.name};
GO
```

And this is what is produced when properties are replaced by Maven:

```
USE [master];
GO
-- Creating logins
CREATE LOGIN CUSTOM_USERNAME WITH PASSWORD = 'CUSTOM_PASSWORD';
GO

-- Creating users for the logins
CREATE USER CUSTOM_USERNAME FOR LOGIN CUSTOM_USERNAME;
GO

-- Granting permissions to the users
GRANT CONNECT TO CUSTOM_USERNAME;
GO

GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO CUSTOM_USERNAME;
GO

USE [msdb];
GO
-- Procedure for the housekeeping job

CREATE PROCEDURE hk_job_starter_CUSTOM_USERNAME
AS
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
        EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME',@step_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME_STEP',@subsystem = N'TSQL',@command = N'USE [CUSTOM_USERNAME]; EXEC PKG_HOUSEKEEPING.CLEANUP_DAILY;',@retry_attempts = 5,@retry_interval = 5;
        DECLARE @start_date VARCHAR(8);
        SELECT @start_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)));
        EXEC sp_add_schedule @schedule_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME_SCHEDULE', @freq_type = 4, @freq_interval = 1, @freq_subday_type = 0x8, @freq_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_date = @start_date, @active_start_time = 010000;
        EXEC sp_attach_schedule @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME', @schedule_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME_SCHEDULE';
        EXEC sp_add_jobserver   @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
        EXEC sp_start_job       @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';

    END;
GO

CREATE USER CUSTOM_USERNAME FOR LOGIN CUSTOM_USERNAME;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON hk_job_starter_CUSTOM_USERNAME TO CUSTOM_USERNAME;
GO
```

Here we need to create a job which calls a procedure every night (housekeeping job). With Oracle this is easy, we just grant the CREATE JOB right and use the DBMS_SCHEDULER package to create the job inside the schema. However in MSSQL the jobs are stored in a "central" location, in same place for all databases. So we thought to add the database name into the job name itself, as we will have several instances of the same database inside the same DB server, with separate names, MyDB1, MyDB2, etc. So we should have jobs like MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_MyDB1, MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_MyDB2, etc. Accordingly, the database name is added to the jobstep name, the schedule name, and the procedure name as well (this procedure will in fact create the job, and will be invoked after the relevant housekeeping procedure is installed by a later SQL script).

As you can see, three instances of the ${custom.db.name} were not replaced, while all others were replaced successfully. Question is, why? We suspect it may be the result of some escaping issue, for some reason Maven sees it as something that should not be replaced? I'm not even sure it makes sense.

Comment: What command are you using to do the property replacement? What does your changelog look like?

Comment: We use following command to launch the process:

`mvn -f pom_mssql_product.xml process-resources -Pliquibase64_01`

Changelog file:

`<databaseChangeLog ...><changeSet id="${custom.db.name}_001" author="xxx"><comment>sql/01_Users.sql</comment><sqlFile dbms="mssql" encoding="utf8" path="sql/01_Users.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" endDelimiter="GO"/></changeSet></databaseChangeLog>`

Environment: Maven 3.6.3 with LiquiBase plugin 3.6.2. Also, the `${custom.dbname}` parameter is successfully replaced in the changeset id to the correct value.

Comment: Also tested with older maven (3.5.0) and newer LiquiBase (3.8.5), exactly the same. I'm not even sure, which component does the property replacing in the SQL file? Maven or LiquiBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we found the solution by trial-and-error. It seems that replacement was only skipped for files with a single '@' sign only:

```
EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
EXEC sp_add_jobserver @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_${custom.db.name}';
```

After adding one more '@' sign, replacement was working immediately:

```
EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME', @enabled = 1;
EXEC sp_add_jobserver @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME', @server_name = N'(LOCAL)';
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME', @step_name = N'MV_HOUSEKEEPING_JOB_CUSTOM_USERNAME_STEP';
```

We still don't know why this works though. We are happy that it does, but it would be good to know why. Any ideas?